# rename part of the filename using perl

Tags: perl

I want to rename part of the file using perl . I know how to rename the filenames having spaces , I made this for the files names has "my 123.log". This code will rename it to new_123.log.

```
foreach my $i (<"my *.log">) {

my $y = $i; # save the original file name

$i =~ s/my /new_/; # replace the spaces with a _ character

rename ( $y, $i ); # rename the original file with the new name
```

Now I want to rename the file named as my.123.log, and I am confused how to deal with this '.' in the file name . also If I want to rename a single file name that start with the name of my (lest say my 123.log) so is this command OK ? I want to use this because I just know the starting of filename

```
move '../my *.log', '../new.log' or die "cant change the name";
```

Comment: What are the *all* the possible names for the original logs?  Having multiple options makes it difficult to account for them.

Comment: the log file has starting name with my and then the date and time like my.22-1-2014-00-33-57.log

So I just want to edit the my to new

Comment: yeah, I defined it as `use File::Copy qw(move);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to find the pattern before handing it off to `move`.  The `move` statement as you have above will overwrite all input files except for the last.  So, you can "save" what matched by using parens(one or more times):

```
/^my\s([a-z0-9])\.log/;

#try this first please
print "move '../my $1.log', '../new$1.log' or die "cant _overwrite_ the file";

#and if that looks ok then try uncommenting this:
#move '../my $1.log', '../new$1.log' or die "cant _overwrite_ the file";
```

I didn't have time to test my regular expression, the character class matches might need to be modified to be once or more, or extended if you think characters other than alpha numeric will be in the filenames.

Comment: Hello , Thanks for the help 

You script is just print what this written in print, I removed the print and tried it but still it didn't work for me

Comment: Don't remove the print, uncoment the last line `move '../my $1.log', '../new$1.log' or die "cant _overwrite_ the file";`

Comment: I commented the last line so that you could review the print first to be sure that the move(or perhaps overwrite) was indeed what you wanted to happen.  If you are not careful, you might not be able to undo these filesystem operations.